# Python/ Openpyxl: Formatting a row across multiple columns based on criteria

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl and I would like to format the borders across a row if column A is in my words list.

My Code:

```
header_style = Font(bold = True)

gone = Side(border_style = 'none')
thick = Side(border_style = 'thick')
thin = Side(border_style = 'thin')

tb_border = openpyxl.styles.borders.Border(
            left = gone,
            right = gone,
            top = thin,
            bottom = thick)


A = ws['A1':'A44']
words =  ['Assets', 'Current Assets', 'Liabilities']
    for cell in ws['A']:
        if cell.value in words:
            cell.font = header_style
            cell.border = tb_border
```

So far, this only makes column A bold and with borders. I would like the cell.font & border to work across the row covering columns A - E.

I also tried,

```
  for row in rows:
            if cell.value in words:
                cell.border = tb_border
                cell.font = header_style
```

But again, this just did the cell as it does say if cell.value in words and if I did row.value instead, it still doesn't work.

**EDIT**

I realise I need to iterate over rows so this is what I have so far, this turns it into a conditional format which is also fine if I can get it to work.

```
for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=None, min_col=None, max_col=5):
    for cell in rows:
        words =  ['Total Assets', 'Total Liabilities & Equity']
        sheet.conditional_formatting.add(f'{cell.coordinate}',
                                             FormulaRule(formula=["=words(A{cell.row}))"],
                                                         border = tb_border))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the selection of cells you want to update. As you are only selecting column A, that is the only one that is getting updated. In the original code you have provided, replace the last 5 lines with this...

```
words =  ['Assets', 'Current Assets', 'Liabilities']
for r_idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=5)):
    if ws.cell(r_idx+1, 1).value in words:
        for cell in row:
            cell.font = header_style
            cell.border = tb_border

wb.save('yourfilename.xlsx')
```

...and you should get what you need... something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any links to the documentation this r_idx (row index) is from? I didn't see it on Openpyxl or Python library

Comment: Hi - `r_idx` is just an integer that is used as a counter. `ws.iter_rows()` iterates through each row in the excel sheet, one row at a time and returns the whole row. Documentation available [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows). Using `enumerate` we also get a counter (which is read into `r_idx`) along with the item (`row` in this case). Hope this helps